# Android show dialpad without manifest permissions

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

Users are complaining about call phone permission in Google Play. How can I show the Android dial pad with pre-populated number from my application without needing permission in the manifest?

Comment: This is not a personal KB. Please don't ask questions you already know the answers for

Comment: I could not find an answer that I wanted and thought this maybe is useful for other users. So after I found how to solve I share it with the rest.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of using Intent.ACTION_CALL or Intent.ACTION_DIAL do the following:

```
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

This will open up the standard Android dial pad with the given number. This way you don't need to use the permissions CALL_PHONE or DIAL. No modification of the manifest.xml is needed.

Comment: getting better ratings is surely not down to your bad practice. Would it not be better to explain what you use each permission for if you think they are off putting

Comment: Maybe it is indeed the bad practice but searching the internet and using the Android documentation it kept referring me to ACTION_CALL and not ACTION_VIEW. And didn't need to call but just go to the dial pad. ACTION_CALL is how it is documented throughout examples, websites etc.. But for most developers it is not needed and just showing a dial pad is enough.

Answer (score 1):

@QVDev you can also use ACTION_DIAL instead of ACTION_VIEW

Comment: it seems so if I read the documentation correctly only the ACTION_CALL needs the permission. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: as @QVDev said, it needs call permission, so please delete your answer

Comment: ACTION_DIAL don't need any permission @MilaDroid